# Using Promises with React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, es6-promise

I'm trying to set my Redux state with some items that depend on an API call.

This is what i have so far.

The Api call ->

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const _items = [];
    axios.get(SiteUrl + spQuery).then((response) => {
       //console.log(response);
        return response.data.d.results;
    }).then((listItemsData) => {
        ......
        _items.push({...});
        return _items;
    }).then((items) => { 
        resolve(items);
    });
});
```

And in my componentDidMount() i tried several things, including ->

```
store.dispatch(addListItem(this.updateSharepointList().then((result) => { return result })));
```

And

```
    store.dispatch(addListItem(this.updateSharepointList()));
```

Both of the calls return the Promise object (with `PromiseValue`) but if i do it like `//let test = this.updateSharepointList().then((result) => { console.log(result) });`

And i use `console.log(test)` it is fine. I get back the array of items.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you display the content of addListItem, it should return an action with payload the item if I am not mistaken ?

Comment: You mean this ? `export const addListItem = listItem => ({ type: ADD_LISTITEM, payload: listItem });
`

The problem is not actually in Redux, its the fact that it is dispatching a promise instead of the `PromiseValue`

Comment: The thing is you pass a promise to the action creator, what you should do is call the API and on success call dispatch with the item you received as addListItem as param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it the problem is that you are passing a promise to the action creator not the actual value.

The action creator should be called when you have the items, when the API call is complete and the promise is resolved.

```
this.updateSharepointList().then((result) => { 
     store.dispatch(addListItem(result)) 
})
```

*If you are using react you could checkout "react-redux" you could checkout connect and binding the action creators to your props. Its a more elegant and easier to work with approach.*

Example using react-redux:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
   doSomething() {
     this.updateSharepointList().then((result) => { 
       this.props.addListItem(result);
     })
   }
}

const mapDipatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
     addListItem: (listItem) => dispatch(addListItem(listItem))
)}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({}) // used for getting state from store and mapping it to props 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks. So the main problem here is that `dispatch()` does not wait for its parameter to fully resolve and thats why i'm getting the entire promise i suppose ?

Edit: Could you show me an example with react-redux ? I literally just started learning redux today so i know pretty much nothing.

Comment: Kinda, the promise doesn't return a value it only return a handler that when executed will execute your callback or then. The promise never return a value.

Comment: Glad to help, keep it up buddy :)